# How to rewrite template function to allow code reuse

Tags: c++, templates, refactoring, recursive-templates

Consider the following template recursion function. Its purpose is to create a vector containing all values in the enum class EnumClassName for which its associated predicate function `bool xxx<N>()` returns `true`.

```
template <EnumClassName N = EnumClassName::LAST_ENUM_VALUE> 
std::vector<EnumClassName> xxx_stuff()
{
    std::vector<EnumClassName> v = xxx_stuff<EnumClassName(static_cast<int>(N) - 1)>();

    if (xxx<N>()) {
        v.emplace_back(N);
    }
    return v;
}
```

with the recursion base case:

```
template <> std::vector<EnumClassName> xxx_stuff<EnumClassName::FIRST_ENUM_VALUE>()
{
    return {};
}
```

Now assume there are 10 of these functions where the only thing that differs is the `xxx` name. I.e. we have the functions `alpha_stuff` with a corresponding predicate function `alpha<N>`, `beta_stuff` with a corresponding predicate function `beta<N>`, etc etc.

Is there any way to not duplicate the above function 10 times, where the only difference is the replacement of `xxx` with `alpha`, `beta` etc in each duplicate?

I am not able to just loop over the enum values, because the `xxx<N>` functions in turn call another function `yyy<N>` which will not accept a runtime-generated template argument `<N>` (forgive my lingo there, I actually have no idea what I'm talking about or how this works, I just know it gave me compilation errors when I tried it that way).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass function template as argument or overloaded function, but you can wrap the call in a type, and then

```
template <typename EnumClassName,
          EnumClassName N = EnumClassName::LAST_ENUM_VALUE,
          typename F> 
std::vector<EnumClassName> xxx_stuff(F&& f)
{
    std::vector<EnumClassName> v =
        xxx_stuff<EnumClassName, EnumClassName(static_cast<int>(N) - 1)>(f);

    if (f(std::integral_constant<EnumClassName, N>{})) {
        v.emplace_back(N);
    }
    return v;

}
```

with usage

```
auto v = xxx_stuff<E>([](auto n) { return xxx<n()>(); });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/77s48f38z)

Note: That recursion can be avoided using [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).

Comment: Thank you! Very nice solution! Although what really helped me was the reference `std::integer_sequence` which I ended up using instead, and avoided the recursion!! Awesome.